# AsyncIO when to create a custom Transport Vs Protocol

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a simple protocol which acts like tcp but works above udp, lets call it supa.

I want to use asyncIO's `create_connection` to create a reader/writer.

I'm struggling to understand the different roles of transport and protocol.

I'm also not sure why Protocol is the one that receives but doesn't sends: In `DatagramProtocol` we have `datagram_received` but no matching send method.

I was able to create my own dumbed down version of  reader/writer and protocol(which inherited from
`DatagramProtocol`). So if this is `create_connection`:

```
async def open_connection(host=None, port=None, *,
                          limit=_DEFAULT_LIMIT, **kwds):
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
    reader = StreamReader(limit=limit, loop=loop)
    protocol = StreamReaderProtocol(reader, loop=loop)
    transport, _ = await loop.create_connection(
        lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
    writer = StreamWriter(transport, protocol, reader, loop)
    return reader, writer
```

I created something like:

```
async def open_connection(host=None, port=None, *,
                          limit=_DEFAULT_LIMIT, **kwds):
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
    reader = SupaReader(limit=limit, loop=loop)
    protocol = SupaProtocol(reader, loop=loop)
    transport, _ = await loop.create_connection(
        lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
    writer = SupaWriter(transport, protocol, reader, loop)
    return reader, writer
```

But doing that means that I have to implement `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` again.
I can't use the current `StreamWriter` because `StreamWriter` writes straight to the transport bypassing the protocol, as we see here:

```
class StreamWriter:

    ...
    @property
    def transport(self):
        return self._transport

    def write(self, data):
        self._transport.write(data)
    ...
```

Which means I can't control the data that is sent to the udp socket (meaning I can't run supa's code).
I thought maybe I should create my own transport layer as well but the docs warn against doing that.

To clear up the question: When and how should one create a custom transport layer?

Thank you!

Comment: Please supplement your question with links to the relevant parts of the documentation and/or source code you are referencing because right now it is not entirely clear, when you refer to existing (stdlib) code vs. your own. For example, are you talking about the event loop's [`create_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_connection) method? Which other existing classes/functions are you talking about?